# How to properly remove an XML tag using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document which is as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<STA_ORDERS>
 <STA_ORDER_LINES>
  <STA_ORDER_LINE>
   <ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>0.0</ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>
   <BRAND_NAME>Test</BRAND_NAME>
   <BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>2.0</BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>
   <BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>PCE</BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <CARD_PRICE_SE>0.0</CARD_PRICE_SE>
   <CONV_FACTOR>1</CONV_FACTOR>
   <CURRENCY_CODE>SEK</CURRENCY_CODE>
   <CURRENCY_RATE>1.0</CURRENCY_RATE>
   <CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <DISCOUNT>0.0</DISCOUNT>
   <ORDER_LINE_NO>1</ORDER_LINE_NO>
   <PART_DESCRIPTION>SHEENA JKT OLIVE L</PART_DESCRIPTION>
   <PART_NO>010008002010</PART_NO>
   <PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>2021-07-02</PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>
   <PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>0.0</PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>
   <PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>1</PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>
   <PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <RELEASE_NO>3</RELEASE_NO>
   <SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>CP</SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>
   <VENDOR_PART_NO>010008002010</VENDOR_PART_NO>
  </STA_ORDER_LINE>
 </STA_ORDER_LINES>
</STA_ORDERS>
```

I need an XSL document to transfer the above xml so that the <RELEASE_NO> will have a leading zero if the release number only has a single digit.

Example 3 => 03, 2 => 02, 10 => 10 (10 already has 2 digits so we just keep it as it is)

I have used the below xsl.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:ifs="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:TYPE_SCHEMA_NAME_HERE" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ifs date">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="STA_ORDER_LINE">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(RELEASE_NO > 9)">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
           <RELEASE_NO>
             <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',RELEASE_NO)"/>
           </RELEASE_NO>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but doesn't seem to work correctly, since it had added the new tag with the correction but the older seems to be still available. (https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html)

[image]

Any ideas??

===============================

Revised XML seems not to work. I have added xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:outbound_distribution_transactions_sta_send_purchase_order_sta_request" to <STA_ORDERS> tag. Any idea why its not working??

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<STA_ORDERS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:outbound_distribution_transactions_sta_send_purchase_order_sta_request">
 <ACTIONTYPE>CREATE</ACTIONTYPE>
 <BUYER>IFS APPLICATIONS</BUYER>
 <COUNTRY_CODE>SE</COUNTRY_CODE>
 <CURRENCY_CODE>SEK</CURRENCY_CODE>
 <CUSTOMER_COMPANY_COUNTRY>SVERIGE</CUSTOMER_COMPANY_COUNTRY>
 <CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME>Stadium Sverige AB</CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME>
 <CUSTOMER_POSTAL_ADDRESS>Norra Promenaden,,602 22 Norrköping,,SVERIGE</CUSTOMER_POSTAL_ADDRESS>
 <DELIVERY_TERMS_CODE>DPC</DELIVERY_TERMS_CODE>
 <DELIVERY_TERMS_DESCRIPTION>023 DDP Norrköping CWH</DELIVERY_TERMS_DESCRIPTION>
 <EAN_LOCATION_DELIVERY_ADDRESS>7350031681995</EAN_LOCATION_DELIVERY_ADDRESS>
 <EAN_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT_ADDRESS>EMCAT1</EAN_SUPPLIER_DOCUMENT_ADDRESS>
 <FUNCTION_CODE>4</FUNCTION_CODE>
 <ORDER_DATE>2021-07-02</ORDER_DATE>
 <ORDER_NO>949</ORDER_NO>
 <ORDER_REVISION>0</ORDER_REVISION>
 <PAY_TERM_DAYS> Da</PAY_TERM_DAYS>
 <PAY_TERM_DESCRIPTION>20 Days Net</PAY_TERM_DESCRIPTION>
 <PAY_TERM_PERIOD>D</PAY_TERM_PERIOD>
 <PAY_TERM_REFERENCE>e</PAY_TERM_REFERENCE>
 <RECEIVER_COMMUNICATION_ID>CONNECT</RECEIVER_COMMUNICATION_ID>
 <SENDER_COMMUNICATION_ID>S17647</SENDER_COMMUNICATION_ID>
 <SHIP_VIA_DESCRIPTION>Car</SHIP_VIA_DESCRIPTION>
 <SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_NO>1</SUPPLIER_ADDRESS_NO>
 <TAXATION_NO>SE556236439701</TAXATION_NO>
 <VENDOR_NO>90054</VENDOR_NO>
 <WANTED_DELIVERY_DATE>2021-07-02</WANTED_DELIVERY_DATE>
 <DEPARTMENT_ID>33</DEPARTMENT_ID>
 <CHANGE>SENT</CHANGE>
 <STA_DELIVER_TO>
  <STA_ORDER_ADDRESS>
   <ADDRESS_1>Ströbogatan 5</ADDRESS_1>
   <CITY>NORRKÖPING</CITY>
   <COUNTRY>SVERIGE</COUNTRY>
   <RECEIVER_NAME>DC Stadium</RECEIVER_NAME>
   <ZIP_CODE>602 23</ZIP_CODE>
  </STA_ORDER_ADDRESS>
 </STA_DELIVER_TO>
 <STA_ORDER_LINES>
  <STA_ORDER_LINE>
   <ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>0.0</ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>
   <BRAND_NAME>Test</BRAND_NAME>
   <BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>2.0</BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>
   <BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>PCE</BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <CARD_PRICE_SE>0.0</CARD_PRICE_SE>
   <CONV_FACTOR>1</CONV_FACTOR>
   <CURRENCY_CODE>SEK</CURRENCY_CODE>
   <CURRENCY_RATE>1.0</CURRENCY_RATE>
   <CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <DISCOUNT>0.0</DISCOUNT>
   <ORDER_LINE_NO>1</ORDER_LINE_NO>
   <PART_DESCRIPTION>SHEENA JKT OLIVE L</PART_DESCRIPTION>
   <PART_NO>010008002010</PART_NO>
   <PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>2021-07-02</PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>
   <PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>0.0</PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>
   <PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>1</PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>
   <PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <RELEASE_NO>1</RELEASE_NO>
   <SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>CP</SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>
   <VENDOR_PART_NO>010008002010</VENDOR_PART_NO>
  </STA_ORDER_LINE>
  <STA_ORDER_LINE>
   <ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>0.0</ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>
   <BRAND_NAME>Test</BRAND_NAME>
   <BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>2.0</BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>
   <BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>PCE</BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <CARD_PRICE_SE>0.0</CARD_PRICE_SE>
   <CONV_FACTOR>1</CONV_FACTOR>
   <CURRENCY_CODE>SEK</CURRENCY_CODE>
   <CURRENCY_RATE>1.0</CURRENCY_RATE>
   <CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <DISCOUNT>0.0</DISCOUNT>
   <ORDER_LINE_NO>1</ORDER_LINE_NO>
   <PART_DESCRIPTION>SHEENA JKT OLIVE L</PART_DESCRIPTION>
   <PART_NO>010008002010</PART_NO>
   <PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>2021-07-02</PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>
   <PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>0.0</PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>
   <PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>1</PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>
   <PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <RELEASE_NO>2</RELEASE_NO>
   <SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>CP</SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>
   <VENDOR_PART_NO>010008002010</VENDOR_PART_NO>
  </STA_ORDER_LINE>
  <STA_ORDER_LINE>
   <ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>0.0</ADDITIONAL_COST_AMOUNT>
   <BRAND_NAME>Test</BRAND_NAME>
   <BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>1.0</BUY_QUANTITY_DUE>
   <BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>PCE</BUY_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <CARD_PRICE_SE>0.0</CARD_PRICE_SE>
   <CONV_FACTOR>1</CONV_FACTOR>
   <CURRENCY_CODE>SEK</CURRENCY_CODE>
   <CURRENCY_RATE>1.0</CURRENCY_RATE>
   <CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</CUSTOMER_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <DISCOUNT>0.0</DISCOUNT>
   <ORDER_LINE_NO>1</ORDER_LINE_NO>
   <PART_DESCRIPTION>SHEENA JKT OLIVE L</PART_DESCRIPTION>
   <PART_NO>010008002010</PART_NO>
   <PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>2021-07-02</PLANNED_DELIVERY_DATE>
   <PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>0.0</PREFERRED_RETAIL_PRICE_SE>
   <PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>1</PRICE_CONVERSION_FACTOR>
   <PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>pcs</PRICE_UNIT_MEASURE>
   <RELEASE_NO>3</RELEASE_NO>
   <SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>CP</SHIPMENT_PARTIAL>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_OUR_CURRENCY>
   <UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>1073.4</UNIT_PRICE_IN_SUPPLIER_CURRENCY>
   <VENDOR_PART_NO>010008002010</VENDOR_PART_NO>
  </STA_ORDER_LINE>
 </STA_ORDER_LINES>
</STA_ORDERS>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

It takes into account a default namespace.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:outbound_distribution_transactions_sta_send_purchase_order_sta_request">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:RELEASE_NO[string-length() = 1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('0', .)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Revised XML seems not to work. I have added only below

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:ifsworld-com:schemas:outbound_distribution_transactions_sta_send_purchase_order_sta_request" to <STA_ORDERS> tag. 

Any idea why its not working??

Comment: @ShankaSomasiri, I updated the answer to take into account the added namespace(s). Never ever omit namespaces from XML documents.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind. I am a bit new to XSL, Your assistance is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me:

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='/STA_ORDERS/STA_ORDER_LINES/STA_ORDER_LINE/RELEASE_NO &gt; 9'>
          <RELEASE_NO>
            <xsl:value-of select="/STA_ORDERS/STA_ORDER_LINES/STA_ORDER_LINE/RELEASE_NO"/>
          </RELEASE_NO>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <RELEASE_NO>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',/STA_ORDERS/STA_ORDER_LINES/STA_ORDER_LINE/RELEASE_NO)"/>
          </RELEASE_NO>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

It failed because you are processing the content twice, once with xsl:value of and once with apply-templates

```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   <RELEASE_NO>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',RELEASE_NO)"/>
   </RELEASE_NO>
```

But there are much cleaner ways of doing it. Yitzhak has shown you one; another would be to use `format-number(RELEASE_NO, '00')`; another (rather sneaky) way is `substring(string(RELEASE_NO + 100)), 2)`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Any ideas on the Revised XML seems not to work part.

Comment: If you have a new question, please raise it as a new question, not as an edit on a previous one. It becomes impossible for anyone to relate questions and answers when you do that. Also, please don't tell us that something "doesn't work" without telling us how it fails - for all we know, it's producing the correct answer but your expectations are wrong.

Comment: Noted @MichaelKay. Thanks